# Using revision in composer

Tags: php, git, composer-php

I want to use a special commit in a repo for my composer build:

```
{
"name": "mystyff/mystuff",
"description": "My stuff",
"type": "drupal-profile",
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"repositories": [
  {
    "packagist": false
  },
  {
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "https://git.drupal.org/project/devel.git"
  },
  {
    "type": "composer",
    "url": "https://packagist.drupal-composer.org"
  }
],
"require-dev": {
    "drupal/devel": "8.x-1.x-dev#a4e7c415a8e744f3a50ebed163f0378b4b4acfb2"
}
}
```

When using composer install/update - I get latest revision from the branch, `c0b5c5f9a8ec688459e7cd03eb6b1008a9d5a194`, not the one that I wanted `a4e7c415a8e744f3a50ebed163f0378b4b4acfb2`.

How ever, if I manually edit composer.lock and and add the revision, it works. So I guess I am doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Tag the commit you want to use with a version. Thats what versions are for: To allow anyone to explicitly reference them without hassle.

The added benefit would be to allow updating to compatible versions if you are using semantic versioning (and if you don't, you can still increment the major version number).

Comment: It is not my repository, so I can not add anything to it. I am just using it in my project (among a bunch of others that I also wan to use revisions from).

Comment: I somehow interpreted your question was related to your own repository.